# How do I cross-compile LLVM/Clang for AArch64 on x64 host?

Tags: cross-compiling, llvm-clang, arm64, raspberry-pi4

I want to use clang-11 on my AArch64 Raspberry Pi 4, running Ubuntu 20.04 Focal. I looked at https://apt.llvm.org/, but AArch64 prebuilt binaries do not seem available?

I tried building clang on the Raspberry Pi directly, but it was very slow and I ran out of space on the SD card eventually.

How do I cross-compile clang myself, on my x64 laptop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Clang now has arm64 (AArch64) prebuilt binaries for in-development versions at https://apt.llvm.org/, so use those if you can. Otherwise, read on!

Building LLVM can be tricky in that it takes lots of computing resources, which makes it hard to iterate with different build options. My first attempt to build trunk version of clang for my AArch64 Raspberry PI ended up with a build for ARM7, and also 30GB in size, which just would not fit on the memory card. Whoops.

## Study documentation on project wiki

The first relevant Clang documentation page is [Building LLVM with CMake](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html). It explains CMake options `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`, `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, and `LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD`.

It is a good idea to set `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel`, or some other value other than the default `Debug`. Debug build of clang will run significantly slower. Customizing `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is necessary, as you do not want to install Clang onto your host system. Give it `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PWD/install`, then copy the install directory to your AArch64 machine.

To decrease the installed size, set `-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=AArch64`. The default there is to build all targets.

### Enable assertions (but probably disable debug info)

If you want to use cutting edge features, which is likely, otherwise, why compile clang, you would want to keep assertions in clang code enabled, and you would want debug symbols. Assertions don't cost us almost anything. The debug info is different: it slows down the compilation (linking) of clang binary itself, makes it run slightly slower, and makes it *significantly* bigger, but it can be worthwhile due to increased debuggability, allowing to submit bug report with a symbolized backtrace if anything goes wrong. Check out [Getting the Source Code and Building LLVM](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-the-source-code-and-building-llvm) and set `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=On` in this case. Also consider `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel`. (If you decide to go with debug info anyways, use `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo`.)

Next up, read [Building a Distribution of LLVM](https://llvm.org/docs/BuildingADistribution.html). The relevant advice is to further minimize installed size by setting `-DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=On -DLLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=On -DLLVM_INSTALL_TOOLCHAIN_ONLY=On`.

Finally, read [How To Cross-Compile Clang/LLVM using Clang/LLVM](https://llvm.org/docs/HowToCrossCompileLLVM.html). This page is helpful even if you plan on using GCC to cross-compile. If you are using Ubuntu Focal, either directly or you are building in a Docker container, you will probably end up with this skeleton of your CMake command like

```
CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-10 CXX=aarch64-linux-gnu-g++-10 cmake ../llvm \
  -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING=True \
  -DLLVM_TARGET_ARCH=AArch64 \
  -DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnueabihf \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a72' \
  -GNinja
```

The options there should be straightforward, except maybe for `LLVM_TABLEGEN` and `CLANG_TABLEGEN`. They have to be specified, because these binaries need to run on the host, but the build compiles them for the target, so it cannot use what it just build. Existing binaries must be provided by you. Although llvm-tblgen can be installed with llvm packages, clang-tblgen is not part of the distribution. That means, you need to do two builds. First, build these two binaries for host (you do not have to build complete LLVM, these two binaries are enough), and then point the cross compilation to them.

```
mkdir build-host
cd build-host
CC=gcc-10 CXX=g++-10 cmake ../llvm -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS='clang;compiler-rt;lld;clang-tools-extra' -GNinja
ninja llvm-tblgen clang-tblgen
```

Now, use these binaries in your cross build, so add to your CMake command

```
-DLLVM_TABLEGEN=/usr/bin/llvm-tblgen-11 -DCLANG_TABLEGEN=/mnt/repos/llvm-project/build-host/bin/clang-tblgen
```

## Start docker

It is advisable to mount the directory with llvm sources into the container from your filesystem. This will make it easier to ship the compilation results out, and also native filesystem is faster than the overlays in docker.

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/mnt --rm -it ubuntu:focal bash
```

## Install dependencies

On Ubuntu 20.04 Focal

```
apt install g++-10-aarch64-linux-gnu libstdc++-10-dev-arm64-cross gcc-10 g++-10
apt install cmake ninja-build python3
```

## Configure

```
mkdir build-aarch64
cd build-aarch64

CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-10 CXX=aarch64-linux-gnu-g++-10 cmake ../llvm \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=On \
    -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING=True \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install \
    -DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnueabihf \
    -DLLVM_TARGET_ARCH=AArch64 \
    -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=AArch64 \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a72' \
    -GNinja \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS='clang;compiler-rt;lld;clang-tools-extra' \
    -DLLVM_TABLEGEN=/mnt/repos/llvm-project/build-host/bin/llvm-tblgen \
    -DCLANG_TABLEGEN=/mnt/repos/llvm-project/build-host/bin/clang-tblgen \
    -DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=On \
    -DLLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=On \
    -DLLVM_INSTALL_TOOLCHAIN_ONLY=On
```

## Compile

Get a powerful build machine, if you can. Linking some of the binaries takes lots of RAM. You should have ~20 GB of memory available to be able to get anywhere in reasonable time, 64 GB would be even better. If it happens that multiple linking tasks running in parallel exhaust your machine memory, try compiling with `ninja -j3` or so, to limit number of parallel tasks to, for example, 3.

```
ninja install -j3
```

Using a different linker is supposed to decrease memory requirements. Supposedly, ld.gold has lower memory requirements while linking.

Comment: Note that debug info is _huge_. If you aren't going to need it, it is best to leave it out. You can most certainly compile LLVM on smaller system (4GB RAM or so), as long as you don't include debug information. Especially link time will be shorter without debug information.
For development, assertions are a good thing however and have little impact on binary size.

Comment: @ayke thanks, I've updated the answer with your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

my environment is `Mac`, not your `Raspberry Pi`, so just for your reference:

- now is 20230429, seem `clang` already support `arm64`~=`AArch64`

  - my clang version

    ```bash
     clang --version         
    Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
    Thread model: posix
    ```
  - here on Mac using `clang` to build for `arm64`

    - `clang -arch arm64 main.c -o main_arm64`
  - compiled file is `arm64` arch

    ```bash
     file main_arm64 
    main_arm64: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
    ```

Comment: My question/answer is about cross compiling the entire LLVM for arm64 (and I happened to use gcc for the compiler), not just cross compiling a single file using clang.